# Is there a glide reflection?

Tags: geometry, reflection

I am looking the following:

Let $g$ be a line that goes through the points $(-2,0)$, $(1,-2)$.

- Is there a glide reflection with fixed line $g$, that maps the point $(-1,0)$ to the point $(0,-2)$ ?
- For each point $Z$ let $\delta_Z$ be a reflection around the point $Z$. For which points $Z$ is $\sigma_g\circ\delta_Z$ a refection along a line?

I have done the following:

- We have that the line $g$ has the equation $2x+3y+4=0$. 
  A fixed line is a line that is mapped to itself, but not every point is mapped to itself but maybe to an other point of the line.

  We have that $P=(-1,0)$ is not on $g$. $P'=(0,-2)$ is the image of that point by the glide reflection.

  We have that the segment $PP'$ gets halved by $g$. 
  Let $Q$ be the midpoint of $PP'$. We have that $Q=\left (-\frac{1}{2},-1\right )$. 
  We have to prove if $Q\in g$. 
  $$2\cdot \left (-\frac{1}{2}\right )+3\cdot (-1)+4=-1-3+4=0 \Rightarrow Q\in g$$

  We have that $P$ reflects along $g$ and then we translate it by $(a,b)$.

  The reflection of $P$ along $g$ is the point $\left (-\frac{21}{13}, -\frac{12}{13}\right )$.

  We add at this point the point $(a,b)$ to get $P'$: 
  $$\left (-\frac{21}{13}, -\frac{12}{13}\right )+(a,b)=(0,-2) \ \Rightarrow \ a=\frac{21}{13}, \ b=-\frac{14}{13}$$

  So, the glide reflection is the following:

  The glide reflection is the composirion of a reflection and a translation. The reflection is along $g$ and then we translate about $\left (\frac{21}{13}, -\frac{14}{13}\right )$.
- A reflection around a point is the composition of two reflection along a line, $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$, where $a$ is perpendicular to $b$.

  So, we have that $\sigma_g\circ\delta_Z=\sigma_g\circ\sigma_a\circ\sigma_b$.

  So, we have a composition of three reflections along a line.

  We have that the composition of two parallel reflections is a translation and that the composition of a reflection and a translation is a glide reflection. 
  So, when $g$ is not parallel to $a$ and $b$ then the composition is a reflection.

Is everything correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question:

Forget about $a $ and $b $.

The composition of a reflexion and a symmetry about a point must be **orientation reversing**. So it is either a reflection or a glide-reflexion.

- If $Z $ is on $g $ then the point $Z $ is fixed so it cannot be a glide-reflection. Thererefore is it a reflexion.
- If not, then you can see that there is no fixed point (try it!). So it is a glide-relfexion.

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: Tell me if you need more help :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first question looks fine to me.
For the second one, the set of points for which it is a reflection is the line $g $  itself, otherwise it is a glide-reflexion.

Comment: Great!! At the second question which points do we get then? The intersection points of all the three lines?

Comment: Why do we have that the set of points for which it is a reflection is the line gg itself, otherwise it is a translation?

Comment: If the point $Z $ is in $g $ then the whole transformation is the reflexion about the perpendicular to $g  $ passing through $Z $

Comment: A useful thing to do is to count the number of fixed points. ;-)

Comment: When $g$ is not parallel to $a$ and $b$ then the composition is a reflection, or not? $g$ is parallel to $a$ and $b$ if these 3 lines have a common point, and that is the point $Z$. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure because $a $ and $b $ can be ANY pair of perpendicular lines passing through $Z $ so it is not relevant to consider if they are parallel to $g $

Comment: But if $g$ would be parallel to $a$ or $b$ then we would get a glide reflection, or not?